# Map relationship to base class in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

If I have classes like

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public DateTime CreatedOn {get;set;}
    public DateTime ModifiedOn {get;set;}

    public IList<ModuleHistory> History {get;set;}
}

public class FirstEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public string FirstEntityProperty {get;set;}
}

public class SecondEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public string SecondEntityProperty {get;set;}
}

public class ModuleHistory
{
    public string Field {get;set;}
    public string FromValue {get;set;}
    public string ToValue {get;set;}

    public BaseEntity Module {get;set;}
}
```

I'd like to have one table for FirstEntities, one table for SecondEntities, and one table for ModuleHistories.  ModuleHistories would, I suppose, need to have a column for BaseEntityId and one for BaseEntityType (FirstEntity, SecondEntity).  My first try at this worked, but caused creation of a BaseEntities table.  Is it possible for EF to map this without the table for the base entity?

Answer (score 0):

To use Table per Concrete Type, use `MapInheritedProperties` to tell EF that the base class properties are part of the sub-class tables.

For EntityTypeConfiguration setups:

```
public class MyEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>
{
  public MyEntityConfiguration()
  {
    Map(x => x.MapInheritedProperties());
    ToTable("MyEntities");
  }
}
```

If you're using modelBuilder to setup the entities then:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Map(m =>
{
  m.MapInheritedProperties();
  m.ToTable("MyEntities");
}
```

**Edit Below**
(also edited example above, the MapInheritiedProperties has to be prior to ToTable)

If you want a child relationship at the base-class level then you should structure the data model as Table per Hierarchy, not Table per Concrete since FK relationships are 1-to-1 between tables. A ModuleHistory cannot have a FK pointing to "either" FirstEntity or SecondEntity.

It is possible to get EF to map this, though I'm not sure about trying it with Code-First.. Using entity configurations:

Given the class structure from the original example:

```
public class FirstEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<FirstEntity>
{
    public FirstEntityConfiguration()
    {
        Map(x => x.MapInheritedProperties());
        ToTable("FirstEntity");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);

        HasMany(x => x.History)
            .WithOptional(x => (FirstEntity)x.Module)
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("ModuleId"));
    }
}

public class SecondEntityConfiguration : SecondEntityConfiguration<SecondEntity>
{
    public SecondEntityConfiguration()
    {
        Map(x => x.MapInheritedProperties());
        ToTable("SecondEntity");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);

        HasMany(x => x.History)
            .WithOptional(x => (SecondEntity)x.Parent)
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("ModuleId"));
    }
}

public class ModuleHistoryConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ModuleHistory>
{
    public ModuleHistoryConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("ModuleHistory");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
    }
}

// This mapping is needed because ModuleHistory's reference to BaseEntity. EF needs to know there is a Key.
    public class BaseEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<BaseEntity>
    {
        public BaseEntityConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(x => x.Id);
        }
    }
```

Then when you fetch either FirstEntity or SecondEntity you will receive any History.

There are a couple of serious caveats to this implementation:

1. You lose FK constraints on Module History, so the database will provide no safeguard for orphans (no cascade delete) or correct associations between history and parent.
2. You have to take responsibility for the PK on your TpCC tables to avoid the possibility of keys being duplicated between FirstEntity and SecondEntity. Options here include a shared sequence between tables, or using UniqueIdentifier (/w NewSequentialId())

Ultimately though you will probably be better off with a Table-per-Hierarchy configuration if you want child references in the base class, otherwise separate the history into two classes and move the relationship up to the implementing classes.

Comment: This still results in the BaseEntities table being created.  I also tried just moving the IList<ModuleHistory> to the 2 entities, but this causes the ModuleHistories table to acquire FirstEntity_Id and SecondEntity_Id columns.  I'd like to just have one -- Entity_Id, plus a discriminator.

Comment: Table per Concrete won't serve you very well with child references in the base class. The issue isn't with EF as you can hack it to work, the issue is with SQL Server. FK relationships are to 1 table only. Editing to show how it can be done with EF with DB First minus FK constraint between child and parent.